# Using PREPARE with INTO in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-8.4

I'm studying the `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` commands to optimize my functions in PostgreSQL, but i have some problems.

I have the following `PREPARE` command:

```
PREPARE my_query(int) AS SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id = $1;
```

So, I need store this result (ID) into a variable, like this:

```
EXECUTE my_query(10) INTO var_1;
```

But I got a syntax error. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: If you are using a [procedural language in a Postgres function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xplang.html), you *must* declare which one. Best show a minimal complete code example for a function (including header and everything), even if it's not working. And why would you tag this pg-9.2 *and* pg-8.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make any sense to me.

If you are trying to execute the prepared statement from within PL/PgSQL than you're out of luck. The `EXECUTE` command is reserved for a different purpose within PL/PgSQL. Not that it would have much use, PL/PgSQL plans are prepared and cached by default anyhow :)

If you are trying to do this outside of PL/PgSQL than the `INTO` would mean you are trying to write the result to a new table. Something you are unlikely to do/need that often.

Comment: If Postgresql plans are prepared and cached by default, so what's use of EXECUTE and PREPARE command?

Comment: That is within the PL/PgSQL context, normally they are not prepared and cached in such a way. That is why the question was unclear to me. Writing to a variable suggest PL/PgSQL.

Comment: I'm not understand your point. I'm trying to use this two line above inside a Postgres Function.

Comment: What language are you using for your function? My guess is `plpgsql`, which means that `EXECUTE` does not run a prepared statement but a dynamic command string (docs here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN )

Comment: Yeah, I'm using plgsql. Which context EXECUTE does run a prepared statement ?

Comment: Anything except plpgsql, but with plpgsql you have no need for this due to caching

Comment: So, when i'm using a DML direct in pgAdmin (not within a function) what language i'm using ?

Comment: Normally you are _always_ using SQL, the notable exception to this is within functions where you specifically specify something like `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.